# I am trying to bake a normal map of a set of objects with transparency

Tags: transparency, normals, baking, normal-map

I have been trying to bake a normal map for a clump of grass I want to put in a game engine. The problem I am facing is that whenever I bake the normal map it ignores the transparency texture on the grass blade models. What could I do to get the bake to take into account the transparency of the objects in the normal map?
[image: This is what keeps happening, on the left you can see there is transparency on the object, but the normal map ignores it.]